# Adding a period between characters in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
species <- c("Dacut","Hhyde","Faffi","Dmelan","Jrobusta")
leg <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df <- data.frame(species, leg)
```

I am trying to add a period (".") between the first and second letter of every character in the first column of a data frame.

```
#End Goal:
#D.acut
#H.hyde
#F.affi
#D.melan
#J.robusta
```

Does anyone know of any code I can use for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sub`, we can find on the zero-width lookbehind `(?<=^.)`, and then replace with a dot.  This has the effect of inserting a dot into the second position.

```
df$species <- sub("(?<=^.)", "\\.", df$species, perl=TRUE)
df$species

[1] "D.acut"    "H.hyde"    "F.affi"    "D.melan"   "J.robusta"
```

Note: If, for some reason, you only want to do this replacement if the first character in the species name be an actual capital letter, then find on the following pattern instead:

```
(?<=^[A-Z])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `substr()` to split the string at the positions:

```
species <- c("Dacut","Hhyde","Faffi","Dmelan","Jrobusta")
leg <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df <- data.frame(species, leg, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df$species <- paste0(
  substr(df$species, 1, 1),
  ".",
  substr(df$species, 2, nchar(df$species))
)
df$species
```

the first `substr()` extracts character 1 to 1, the second extracts character 2 to last character in string. With `paste()` we can put the `.` in between.

Or `sub()` with a back-reference:

```
df$species <- sub("(^.)", "\\1.", df$species)
```

`(^.)` is the first character in the string grouped with `()`. `sub()` replaces the first instance with the back-refernce to the group (`\\1`) plus the `.`.